# about autostart, lxterminal, and synergy

Tags: raspbian, mouse

I edited this file in hopes of getting a command to run at startup of the GUI in Raspbian:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

I added this line:

```
@/home/pi/startup.sh
```

which contains the following:

```
lxterminal
/usr/local/bin/synergyc <server ip address>
```

lxterminal does open as expected, but the command to start synergy as a client does not work. I already gave the server a static ip and already began running synergy on the server. It works if I manually enter the full synergyc command after startup.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I could use an option in the lxterminal command to run the desired synergy command:

```
lxterminal -l -e '/usr/local/bin/synergyc <server ip address> ; /bin/sh '
```

The only thing I'm trying to work out is how to avoid this -l option and still have the terminal open, rather than just flash open and close.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.